# MVCSiteMapProvider specify target

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvcsitemapprovider

I am well into setting up my sitemap using `MVCSiteMapProvider`.

I have a situation where I need to specify the `SiteMapTitle`. From the documentation I have this:

```
[SiteMapTitle("Title")]
[SiteMapTitle("Genre.Name", Target = AttributeTarget.ParentNode)]
```

The title works fine, but because my parent node is dependent on some dynamic attributes I need to define these in my Target, as they can't be defined in the xml site map.

e.g. I want to specify my target to something like this.

```
/Genre/pop
```

I only seem to be able to set the `Target` to `CurrentNode` or `ParentNode`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Your question is unclear. What exactly do you mean by "dynamic attributes"? If using dynamic node provider, `SiteMapTitle` is unnecessary - it is only for use when you are [forcing a match](http://www.shiningtreasures.com/post/2013/09/02/how-to-make-mvcsitemapprovider-remember-a-user-position#forcing-a-match).  The target specifies which *node* will be overwritten by the property of the view model you specify (the name of the SiteMapTitle attribute). It has nothing at all to do with the URL (which is what you seem to be indicating here). Please clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your comments. I used dynamic node provider to achieve my requirements. When I first read the documentation I thought it was doing something else.